# Azure AD Auditing

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to audit the removal of a user from Azure AD from the perspective of the user being deleted? I.e if John Doe is removed from the AAD is it possible to search the directory for that removal on the name John Doe?

It seems that it is possible to see that Jane Doe removed John Doe, but in that instance you need to know who deleted the account, which for an org of several hundred ops people is effectively impossible to do.

Thanks
Cassie

Can audit on who removed the account, not the removed account.

Answer (score 0):

The Audit logs will contain the information you are looking for.  The date/time, activity, status, target object, and the actor information are all available.

If you navigate to the Azure AD, Users screen you will find the Audit logs option within the Activity section.

From this screen you can do some pretty advanced filtering as well so you filter down the specific activity types (ex. "Delete User") or you can search by the target or the actor.

When searching for the delete activity types, if you want to specify the target, you will need to search for it via the user's guid and not the username since the delete activity type will show a composite value of the guid+username.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to audit the removal of a user from Azure AD from the perspective of the user being deleted? I.e if John Doe is removed from the AAD is it possible to search the directory for that removal on the name John Doe?

Of course, navigate to the Azure Active Directory in the portal -> `Users` -> `Deleted users` -> search by Name.

[image]

> It seems that it is possible to see that Jane Doe removed John Doe, but in that instance you need to know who deleted the account, which for an org of several hundred ops people is effectively impossible to do.

I think it is possible. You could navigate to the `Users` -> `Audit logs`. Choose the filter like the screenshot, **note** the target should be the object id of the account which was deleted, then the `INITIATED BY (ACTOR)` is the one who deleted the account. If you have other requirements, just change the filter.

[image]

**Besides**, you can also use the Microsoft Graph API: [**List directoryAudits**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-beta) to get the one who deleted the account, the `2a167196-12dxxxxxxx068824f2` is the object id of the account which was deleted.

*Sample*:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/directoryAudits?&filter=activityDisplayName eq 'Delete user' and targetResources/any(t:t/id eq '2a167196-12dxxxxxxx068824f2')
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't that still mean I need to know the details of the account deleted...in this instance including the GUID.

I'm after the ability to do a search on Azure AD for what users were deleted...the portal will show who has been deleted under 30 days and then nada; gone. The Graph Explorer seems to need details which aren't obvious and so we still, seemingly have a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: @CassandraJones At least you need to know the user principal name(e.g. testuser@testorg.onmicrosoft.com), search for the log of creating the user via the name, then you can get the object id. I think this is just the basic information of the user, not the details. If you know nothing, you want to get it, I think it is unreasonable. Or you can check the logs one by one. About the deleted users, the portal will show who has been deleted under 30 days, this is by designed and I think it is reasonable enough. This should not be saved forever, right?

Comment: @CassandraJones I think my reply is clear enough, if you think it is helpful, please mark it as the answer(on the left of my reply, there is an option to mark), thanks.